# Bash: How to trim whitespace before using cut

Tags: bash, trim, cut

I have a line of output from a command like this:

```
[]$ <command> | grep "Memory Limit"
Memory Limit:           12345 KB
```

I'm trying to pull out the 12345. The first step - separating by the colon - works fine

```
[]$ <command> | grep "Memory Limit" | cut -d ':' -f2
           12345 KB
```

Trying to separate this is what's tricky. How can I trim the whitespace so that `cut -d ' ' -f1` returns "12345" rather than a blank?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Pipe your command to awk, print the 3rd column, a space and the 4th column like this

```
<command> | awk '{print $3, $4}'
```

This results in:

```
12345 KB
```

or

```
<command> | awk '{print $3}'
```

if you want the naked number.

Comment: I would suggest to replace `" "` with `,` as `awk` has a default `OFS` whose value is single space. Existing command is not wrong just having some unwarranted stuff in it. Example `awk '{print $3" " $4}'` and `awk '{print $3,$4}'` would result in same output in case of default `OFS`.

Comment: @PS. Of course you are right. Thanks a lot for the hint. I have made a change in my post.

Answer (score 12):

[tr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) helps here.

```
$ echo "Memory Limit:           12345 KB" | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f3
12345
```

- `tr -s " "` - squeeze all spaces into one
- `cut -d " " -f3` - split into columns by space and select third

Answer (score 6):

You can use `awk` and avoid using any cut, sed or regex:

```
<command> | awk '/Memory Limit/{print $(NF-1)}'

12345
```

- `/Memory Limit/` will make this print only a line with `Memory Limit` text
- `$(NF-1)` will get you `last-1`th field in input.

Comment: Presumably `<command>` outputs more lines than the one containing "Memory Limit".  It wouldn't be hard to make `awk` select that wanted line instead of using a separate `grep`, but you need to do one or the other.

Comment: Yes in that case: `<command> | awk '/Memory/{print $(NF-1)}'` should work

Answer (score 3):

do you have to use `cut`? `cut` is only for single character delimiter extraction. i don't think cut can be as easy as you would expect.

`sed` is straightforward:

```
$ echo "Memory Limit:           12345 KB" | sed 's/.*:\s*//'
12345 KB
```

explanation:

`.*:\s*` matches all letters before the last colon, then matches all the empty chars after that and delete them by substituting to an empty string.

---

it turns out that you were expecting a single number. then i would say just go ahead and match the numbers:

```
$ echo "Memory Limit:           12345 KB" | grep -o -P '\d+'
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is perhaps the best for this task, but here is an unorthodox way

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=Memory Limit:)\s+[0-9]+" file | xargs
```

lookbehind for matching the label and output only matching, use xargs to eat up spaces

Answer (score 1):

`bash` also has regular expression matching you can use.

```
result=$(<command> | grep "Memory Limit")
regex='Memory Limit:[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]KB'
if [[ $result =~ $regex ]]; then
  result=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
else
  # deal with an unexpected result here
fi
```

The value of `$regex` can be adjusted as necessary.