# How to use cut to trim the first x variable spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, cut

I have a file that is like this:

```
              67 lol
             143 hi
              21 test
               1 ciao
               5 lo
```

I want to remove the spaces.

```
67 lol
143 hi
21 test
1 ciao
5 lo
```

I know that I can use sed to do that, for example with:

```
cat ciao | sed 's/[[:space:]]*\([[:digit:]]* .*\)/\1/' | sort -g
```

but my professor says that I can easily use cut to do that... but I really don't know how.

Something like this:

```
cat ciao | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

would not work because I lose the number information.
lol
hi
test
ciao
lo

Comment: Using `GNU sed`, it's easier : `sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' file`

Comment: Maybe [How do I trim leading and trailing whitespace from each line of some output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606459/279389) was meant.

Comment: `cut` is the wrong tool.  So is `sed`.  Use `tr -s ' '`.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693265/how-to-use-cut-to-trim-the-first-x-variable-spaces

Comment: `read a b` will give you two fields as variables

Comment: Do not cross-post on multiple sites, please.

Comment: @User123 I know how to use sed, I also wrote that I used sed to get it working, but I was curious on how to do it with cut.

Comment: @WilliamPursell same as the above comment

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nope, because I also need the numbers, and that way I erase the numbers :/

Comment: there's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46926851) which uses `cut` ... but it also uses `tr` to `s`queeze out extra spaces

Comment: I found an answer myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71382100/5953720

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:
I can do this:

```
cat ciao | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2 | rev
```

to not lose the number information. works!